# Controlling save button enabled/disabled state programmatically

Tags: ckeditor

How would I enable/disable the save button of CKEditor using external JS? I don't want to remove it completely, just change the appearance between gray and colored icon so that it's more user friendly.

My save button is generated like so:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save'] =
{
    init : function( editor )
    {
        var command = editor.addCommand( 'save', {
            modes : { wysiwyg:1, source:1 },
            exec : function( editor ) {
                if(My.Own.CheckDirty())
                    My.Own.Save();
                else
                    alert("No changes.");
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Save',{label : '',command : 'save'});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

For 3.6.x:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.getCommand( 'save' ).disable();
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.getCommand( 'save' ).enable();
```

For 4.x:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.commands.save.disable();
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.commands.save.enable();
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for leading me to the right tracks. I had to change it a little because my instance didn't have a "commands" variable, I used `CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.getCommand('save').disable()`

Comment: Thanks, I checked it on CKEditor 4.x where `getCommand()` is no longer necessary. Updated my answer.